# How to Code PHP in Dreamweaver

Tags: php, dreamweaver, notepad++

Excuse me , I was going to code PHP in dreamweaver bcoz I was tired to code in notepad++ (which is must be manually check and no spell-autocorrect in n++ :( )
My dreamweaver version is CS5 and I want to Code PHP 5.3.8 with XAMPP 1.7.3

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: And what is your question? Actually, whatever it is, it's somewhat off topic here as it doesn't pertain to a problem in programming. Try http://superuser.com for help with how to use applications.

Comment: On StackOverflow users usually ask questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using Netbeans IDE, great and useful program.
To code in dreamweaver open php file as dreamweaver and at the bottom of screen press on 'Code' tab.

Answer (score 0):

there is also split view. which shows code and design  view at single time

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Dreamweaver for PHP coding. It was built with Html/Css in mind. Not PHP.

Here is a shortlist of existing PHP editors :

- Aptana
- Eclipse PHP
- Netbeans
- PHPStorm

EDIT : It appears that in latter versions of Dreamweaver you can code PHP, but I really wouldn't.

Comment: Actually you can, but I wouldn't

Comment: LOL? http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/php.html

Comment: If you code PHP with Dreamweaver, you're the funny guy.

Comment: Depends on your preference. Dreamweaver has been supporting PHP since around 2005. Obviously you're behind on information about the subject.

Comment: For real? And you have an MS Access database and do design in Paint, right? Comon, real tools for real work. Dreamweaver is one of the worst web development tools existing. Giving people the impression they do good work and that they know what they do.

Answer (score 0):

If you are switching to Dreamweaver just because you don't want to code in Notepad++ then I suggest you better use [Zend Eclipse PDT](http://www.zend.com/en/community/pdt/downloads) instead.